# How can I use the seasonal library in R to add seasonal outliers to the ARIMA model?

Tags: r, seasonal-adjustment

There isn't a specific function in the seasonal package to add seasonal outliers in the regression when calculating seasonal factors but I am wondering if there's a well-known workaround that people have come up with.